# How to Select From Mysql table With Escapable Characters

Tags: java, mysql

i am trying to select tables from my mysql database , and the tables names may be any thing unsafe, since users choose them, i have tried to do it like this :

```
String table = "*jjs> o";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.PrepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ? ");
stmt.setString(1,table);
stmt.executeQuery();
```

but seems it to throw exception due to unacceptable command, can some one help me how can i achieve that please? thanks

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''*jjs> o'' at line 1

Comment: Catch the SQLException and do what you want to do if user inputs an invalid table name

Comment: not an option mate, i want them to input what they want, there must be a way?

Comment: Read the message, and do what is suggested RTFM.

Comment: if not i think encoding will be a must for me

Comment: I'd fire anyone creating a table with such an kinky name.

Comment: you wont fire any thing at a 1year old baby playing with mobile :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a back tick(`) to table name

`` select * from `*jjs> o` ``

Comment: posted answer 1 sec after you :D any way

Answer (score 0):

Ok Using BackTicks  Was the Answer, Like  `` select * from `*jjs> o` `` without statement.Thanks Alot

Comment: thats what I was searching for backticks was not visible.Edited your answer :)

Comment: ye noticed , but yours is accepted, who will look mine, hehe